# Get range identifier from range object excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code that works on named ranges that are set up externally. How can I get the actual cell reference from this range? For example

```
Dim rangeID As String
rangeID = ActiveSheet.Range("MyNamedRange").UnknownFunction
```

Sets `rangeID` to "CG13" if the named range "MyNamedRange" refers to CG13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveSheet.Range("MyNamedRange")` already is the "actual cell reference." It references the cell object. You should [directly use that object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683) anywhere you need a cell in your code.

The textual representation of the address of that cell is `ActiveSheet.Range("MyNamedRange").Address`. You can provide parameters to get the address in the form you want (e.g. to get "CG13" you call `Address(False, False, xlA1)`).

Comment: Sorry, I am referring to "actual cell reference" as the Excel meaning of reference that you use to refer to other cells in the workbook, rather than the VBA meaning of reference meaning a variable referring to that range. But thank you, `Address` is exactly what I am looking for.